# Get User id on hourSegmentClicked event of Angular Calendar Day View Scheduler

Tags: angular

I am using `Angular Calendar 6.0+` in my project and displaying `day-view-scheduler` on a page with 3 users.

When a user clicks on an empty segment, I can get date and time using `hourSegmentClicked` event but in addition to that I also need the column index or user id.

I am using [this](https://angular-calendar.com/#/day-view-scheduler) demo.

[image]

Following is my code on a page

```
<day-view-scheduler
        [viewDate]="viewDate"
        [users]="staff"
        [events]="events"
        (eventTimesChanged)="eventTimesChanged($event)"
        (userChanged)="userChanged($event)"
        (hourSegmentClicked)="createBooking($event)"
        >
</day-view-scheduler>
```

`$event` only provides date, how do i get the column number?

Thank you

Comment: `$event.event.meta.user` to get the user?

Comment: Not when an existing event is clicked, I need the column number when empty `hourSegment` is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to include the userId in the event:

1. Look for the line

```
<div class="cal-day-column" *ngFor="let column of view.hourColumns; trackBy: trackByHourColumn">
```

and change it to collect the loop index like this:

```
<div class="cal-day-column" *ngFor="let column of view.hourColumns; let i = index; trackBy: trackByHourColumn">
```

Note that the variables in the demo are poorly named ("hourColumn"), these are actually the user columns. Helps to understand what's going on.

2. Look for the `<mwl-calendar-week-view-hour-segment`, attribuite `(mwlClick)=`. Extract the code there into a method of the component and pass in the index `i` that we introduced above:
   `(mwlClick)="onHourSegmentClicked($event, segment.date, i)"`
3. The method me just introduced should be in day-view-scheduler.component.ts.
   Add the userId to the emitted event like this:

```
onHourSegmentClicked($event: MouseEvent, date: Date, columnIndex: number) {
    this.hourSegmentClicked.emit({
      date: date,
      sourceEvent: $event,
      userId: this.users[columnIndex].id
    } as any)
  }
```

Unfortunately, we have to circumvent the type system here, using the cast to `any`. The reason is that the `hourSegmentClicked` EventEmitter in the base class is declared to emit events that only contain date and source event. We need to add something to the event, but we can not redeclare the type of the EventEmitter, that's why we're casting the event to `any`. I'd usually avoid that, but I don't see a better option (other than changing the library code).

4. Now in the parent component that handles the event, we can read the userId out of the event. Not type-safe, but it works.